# Как исправить ошибку python?

Tags: python

1) Массив содержит четное количество элементов. Напишите программу, которая сортирует первую половину массива по возрастанию, а вторую – по убыванию. Каждый элемент должен остаться в «своей» половине.
Пример:
Массив:
5 3 4 2 1 6 3 2
После сортировки:
2 3 4 5 6 3 2 1

```
A = list(map(int, input().split()))
l = len(A)
if l % 2 == 0:
    l = l / 2
    a1 = sorted(A[:l])
    a2 = sorted(A[l:], reverse=True)
    A = a1 + a2
    print(*A)
else:
    print('error')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 5, in 
    k = sorted(A[:l])
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо использовать целочисленное деление. Так как при обычном получается дробное число (даже если делится нацело).

```
A = list(map(int, input().split()))
l = len(A)
if l % 2 == 0:
    l = l // 2
    a1 = sorted(A[:l])
    a2 = sorted(A[l:], reverse=True)
    A = a1 + a2
    print(*A)
else:
    print('error')
```